# using ggplot for predicted response of zero inflated GLM

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a glm that I have plotted with ggplot to look the predicted response curve with confidence intervals as below, and it works perfectly:

```
glm7 <- glm(dataset_presence$dcalls ~ dataset_presence$ui_avg, family=poisson(link="log"))
summary(glm7)

p7 <- ggplot(dataset_presence, aes(ui_avg, dcalls)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = poisson(link = "log")))

p7 + scale_y_log10() + ggtitle("Predicted dcalls as function of upwelling index") + xlab("upwelling index") + ylab("log10(dcalls)") + geom_label(x=20, y=1, label="p<2e-16")
```

I want to do this for the zero inflated version of this model, something like this, but I do not know what I would have to include for `ggplot(dataset_presence, aes(zeroinfl` to do this:

```
glm7.zero <- zeroinfl(formula = dataset_presence$dcalls ~ dataset_presence$ui_avg | dataset_presence$ui_avg, data = dataset_presence, dist = "poisson", link = "log")

summary(glm7.zero)

p7.zero <- ggplot(dataset_presence, aes(zeroinfl(ui_avg, dcalls)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = poisson(link = "log"))) 

p7.zero + scale_y_log10() + ggtitle("Predicted dcalls as function of upwelling index") + xlab("upwelling index") + ylab("log10(dcalls)") + geom_label(x=20, y=1, label="p<2e-16")
```

Comment: Hi Susannah. We don't have your `dataset_presence` object, nor much of a clue about its structure, so it is going to be very difficult for anyone to give you a tested solution here. Are you able to edit your question with the result of `dput(dataset_presence)` added to it?

Comment: While you don't follow @AllanCameron's advice and post an example data set, I would remove `dataset_presence$` from the `glm` and `zeroinfl` formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks.

Yes, here is the dataset:

> head(dataset_presence)
> Date  Int_Bk    ui_avg     ui_sd dcalls sep2 presence  ui_lag02
> 5  2016-01-12 -9044.3  1.136538  4.502629     41    2        1        NA
> 6  2016-01-13 -8761.7 -1.841046 12.318525     17    0        1        NA
> 7  2016-01-14 -8930.4  3.887893 12.243056      0    1        1  1.136538
> 8  2016-01-15 -9267.8 10.980019  7.707563      0    0        0 -1.841046
> 9  2016-01-16 -9092.2 19.544113 15.408313      0    0        0  3.887893
> 10 2016-01-17 -9146.0  1.304933 13.310565      0    0        0 10.980019

> dput(dataset_presence)
> structure(list(Date = structure(c(16812, 16813, 16814, 16815,
> 16816, 16817, 16818, 16819, 16820, 16821, 16822, 16823, 16824,
> 16825, 16826, 16827, 16828, 16829, 16830, 16831, 16832, 16833,
> 16834, 16835, 16836, 16837, 16838, 16839, 16840, 16841, 16842, ...........